# Android TabBar Style not scaling to full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-styles, android-tablelayout

This is my current TabBar Style

```
  <style name="SM5Theme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_highlight</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_textcolor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
  </style>
```

TabBarBackground:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_non_selected"/>
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected"/>
  <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tab_highlight"/>
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

tab_bar_background_selected:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="-3dp" android:left="-3dp" android:right="-3dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <stroke android:color="@color/tab_bottom_bar" android:width="3dp"/>
      <solid android:color="@color/tab_background_selected"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

This works satisfactory on generating the Tab Theme and underline color. However, the problem is it's doesn't scale all the way.

[image]

How can I solve this? I don't want to use sherlock or the android theme generator.

Comment: Any reason not to use new `TabLayout` with `Toolbar`?

Comment: Can you show me an example? As someone brand new to android, I'm not very familiar of different ways to style the tabbar

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Comment: I am using Xamarin and I would have to add 3mb worth of packages to get it working on mine. I feel like this could be one or two line fix with fill_parent. I would like to see if I can figure out a way using this method at this time.